# Using UseEffect Hook to Fetch API

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, jsx

I am trying to fetch cryptocurrency data from an api, by updating my state with the information pulled up. But when I do, my console.log is showing an empty object. And there is no data being passed down to my child components either. Did I do something wrong here?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import SmallBox from './SmallBox';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [smallData, setSmallData] = useState({})

  async function getAPI(){
    await fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false
    `)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setSmallData({data})); 
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    getAPI();
    console.log(smallData)
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="app">
      
      {/* SmallBox - balance */}
      <SmallBox className="balance"/>
      
      {/* SmallBox - bitcoin */}
      <SmallBox className="bitcoin" coin={smallData}/>
      
      {/* SmallBox - ethereum */}
      <SmallBox className="ethereum" coin={smallData}/>
      
      {/* SmallBox - ripple */}
      <SmallBox className="ripple" coin={smallData}/>
      
      {/* SmallBox - tether */}
      <SmallBox className="tether" coin={smallData}/>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `getAPI` is an `async` function. When you call `console.log` the state is not updated yet.

Comment: Both your API call and react state changes are asynchronous, you can' print the state value on the next line and see it updated

Answer (score 2):

Try `await`ing for the data to be fetched before logging it, instead of await for the fetch inside the `async` function `getAPI`:

```js
  function getAPI(){
    return fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false
    `)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setSmallData({data})); 
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    getAPI()
      .then(() => console.log(smallData));
  }, []); // <- Add dependencies here
```

Note: I think `getAPI` is going to be called on every render of the component, which I don't think it's what you want. I suggest to add some dependency to the second variable (an empty array) passed to the `useEffect` function, telling React to call this effect only when that/those variables have changed. For example, you can add the currency.

Comment: This would return a warning about creating race conditions since useEffect is  synchronous function. To prevent it, as other suggests it is better to create async function inside useEffect and await inside that

Comment: @AmirNabaei, you're right. Changed `await` with `then` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
async function getAPI(){
    const rawData = await fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false`)
    const jsonData = rawData.json();
    setSmallData( state => ({...jsonData}) );
  }

useEffect(() => {
    getAPI().then(() => console.log(smallData));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

**change useEffect wait for the getApi function to finish.**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getAPI().then((_) => {
      console.log(smallData);
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `console.log` should display `{}` because that's the initial state of `smallData`, and `getAPI` will be executed asynchronously. There's nothing wrong about that.

But with your problem of no data being passed down to children components, it might be because you are setting the `smallData` to `{ data: *api response* }`, maybe you want `smallData` to be the api response, instead of an object with a `data` property.

I would suggest to put `console.log(smallData)` just before the return statement, just to see its content in every render.

If you still are facing problems, add the `SmallBox` component code, maybe the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Your React set State hooks are called asynchronously. Thus, your `smallData` will show the previous state because the component has not rerendered yet.

You didn't do anything wrong. See below for commented out code to see what's going on.

```js
  useEffect( () => {
    getAPI(); // 1. This call seems to be correct, and queues up setSmallData. 
    // 2. The state update has not happened yet, but the setSmallData call is queued up. 
    console.log(smallData) // 3. still {} because the state has not been updated yet, and thus is still showing the current state. 

  }, []);
```

In other words, the console.log(smallData) runs BEFORE your setSmallData, and that's why you see an empty object(because `{}` is your initial state). If you displayed the data somewhere on the page however, you will notice that the component rerenders with the data.

You can try:

```js
    async function getAPI(){
      return await fetch(`...`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => data); 
    }
    useEffect( () => {
     async function getApiAndSetState() {
     let data = await getAPI(); // the code pauses here until getAPI() completes.
     console.log(data); // this data is now available
     setSmallData(data);
     }
   }, []);
```